# What kind of indexes should be created on a volumnious table used in a join in sql query?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization, oracle12c

For the following query. `ITEM_CTY_TAR_T` is a volumnious table with 10 million+ rows. I have created primary index on this table with columns `ITEM_NO, ITEM_TYPE, GA_CODE_IMP, GA_TYPE_IMP, TAR_NO` and `VALID_DATE_FROM` but on explaining the plan for this query, the optimizer did a FULL scan on the table. What index should be created to prevent full scan?

```
SELECT
    t.item_no, t.item_type, t.BU_CODE_RU, t.tar_no,
    VALID_DATE_FROM 
FROM
    (SELECT  
         tar.item_no, tar.item_type,
         org.BU_CODE_RU, tar.tar_no, tar.VALID_DATE_FROM,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tar.ITEM_NO, tar.ITEM_TYPE, org.BU_CODE_RU 
                            ORDER BY VALID_DATE_FROM DESC, tar.tar_no DESC) AS RowNumber  
     FROM 
         (SELECT 
              item_no, item_type, tar_no, valid_date_from,
              GA_CODE_IMP 
          FROM 
              ITEM_CTY_TAR_T tar 
          WHERE  
              GA_TYPE_IMP = 'CTY' 
              AND DATE '2023-08-06' >= TRUNC(tar.VALID_DATE_FROM)
              AND DATE '2023-08-06' <= NVL(trunc(tar.VALID_DATE_TO), DATE'9999-12-31')
              AND NVL(trunc(tar.DELETE_DATE), DATE '9999-12-31') >  DATE '2023-08-06') tar,
         (SELECT
              BU_CODE_RU, GA_CODE_CTY 
          FROM
              store_t 
          WHERE
              BU_TYPE = 'SO' AND BU_CODE_RU IS NOT NULL) org
     WHERE
         org.GA_CODE_CTY = tar.GA_CODE_IMP) t  
WHERE
    rownumber = 1
```

[image]

Comment: Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info) then [edit] your questtion to show us the information we need to help you.

Comment: <a target="_blank" href="https://imageupload.io/r3NJbons6Kfjzi0"><img  src="https://imageupload.io/ib/rOYevEFVwMRXjl5_1691419540.png" alt="item_cty_tar.PNG"/></a>

Comment: Above is the explain plan for the query

Comment: Please use universal measurements instead of local words like *crore* that not everyone understands.

Comment: You need an index that is relevant to the columns that you are filtering on in the WHERE clause. In your case that is really only GA_TYPE_IMP; you could also include one of the date columns but you'd either have to change your SQL to stop using TRUNC on the date columns (which is not really doing anything, anyway) or use a functional index to allow for the TRUNC

Comment: `function(any_perfectly_indexed_column)` will defeat the purpose of an index unless you create an index on that same expression.

Comment: Addressing the TRUNC will not resolve OP's issue. These are inequality predicates on two columns. There is no way to binary search a tree for both (at most one of them). This makes index use to support type-2 (from + to dates) tables quite problematic. In OP's case they probably are best off without indexes

Comment: I'd suggest partition by range valid_date_to and use default value '31-dec-3000' for valid_date_to. Also bitmap indexes might help. Yet, if the table is used for OLTP, then do not create any bitmap index on it.  Those trunc won't help.

Comment: @BogdanDincescu , on what columns bitmap index should be created ?

Comment: I mean you may create bitmap indexes on whatever column(s) you query most frequently. If you have several bitmap indexes for individual columns and you have a where clause which searches for values in those columns Oracle may do an index_combine, which in  some cases performs better than a full table scan. Bitmap indexes take less space than b-tree indexes and include also null values, but they are not to be used in tables for OLTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want indexes to be used for this query. Indexes are only faster than full table scans when the ratio of target rows to the table size is extremely small. That is not likely to be the case here.

You're looking for records active as of a given day, but in most type-2 tables that's a significant portion if not a majority of the table. Neither `GA_TYPE_IMP = 'CTY'` nor `BU_TYPE = 'SO'` are likely to narrow down your results enough to justify index use. A full table scan is optimal in this situation.

I suggest that instead of looking at indexes, you hint the query for a modest amount of parallelism:

```
SELECT /*+ parallel(4) */
    t.item_no, t. . . .
```

Now, *if* your records undergo constant change whereby your typical row version lasts only for a day or so and you have thousands of versions per key such that asking for records active as of Aug 6 2023 will give you only a tiny percentage of the table (much less than 1%), *and* you typically only want a very recent date (like today or yesterday), then those from/to dates become important and that may push you to want to use indexes. If that's the case, then your best bet is a combined index but it won't perform well - it will start at the right place on the first column (`VALID_DATE_FROM`) but will have to scan the remainder of the index to test the other column (`VALID_DATE_TO`):

```
CREATE INDEX i_index ON ITEM_CTY_TAR_T (VALID_DATE_FROM,VALID_DATE_TO);
```

And to use it at all you'd have to remove your date functions on at least the leading column:

```
 AND DATE '2023-08-06' + 1 > tar.VALID_DATE_FROM
 AND DATE '2023-08-06' < NVL(tar.VALID_DATE_TO, DATE'9999-12-31')
```

Because your predicate on the first indexed column is an inequality, there's no hope of seeking on the second column so having a function there doesn't really hurt. But scanning the remainder of the index *if* you are looking at only recent dates *might* be cheaper than scanning the full table since the narrower index, especially only the tail end of it, will be smaller.

Index scanning however uses inefficient single block reads following a linked list of non-contiguous blocks, and each row found that matches the predicates is another inefficient single block read from the table segment. This can really add up. Whereas a full table scan uses much more efficient multiblock reads on a single pass and can also bypass the buffer cache and use parallelism, so is much more efficient at reading large volumes of data. Which one is better can only really be known by testing in your environment with your data.

Comment: There is a DELETE_DATE Column also on the same table , do we also need to consider that ?

Comment: I had created following index and then explained the plan for the query :                                                  CREATE INDEX i_index ON ITEM_CTY_TAR_T (GA_TYPE_IMP,VALID_DATE_FROM,VALID_DATE_TO,DELETE_DATE);

Comment: SELECT /*+i_index*/ item_no ,item_type,tar_no,valid_date_from ,GA_CODE_IMP FROM ITEM_CTY_TAR_T tar WHERE GA_TYPE_IMP='CTY' 
                            AND   DATE '2023-08-07'+1  > tar.VALID_DATE_FROM
       AND (  DATE '2023-08-07'-1 < tar.VALID_DATE_TO OR tar.VALID_DATE_TO IS NULL )
       AND (  tar.DELETE_DATE >  DATE '2023-08-07' OR tar.DELETE_DATE  IS NULL )

Comment: Even after modifying the query , optimizer is performing FULL Scan , plz help me out in this

Comment: @radha, my post basically says you don't want to use indexes. Why do you think it should?

Comment: After removing Trunc and NVL Functions , optimizer sgould perform fast full scan as index is created on the columns so why is optimizer not using the index ?

Comment: Oracle's optimizer doesn't work like that. It makes judgment calls based on its cardinality estimates and tries to pick the most optimal method, which often is *not* using indexes. After adding the parallel hint I suggested in my answer, how long does the query take? Is it acceptable?

Comment: Yes its acceptable , but unfortunately its an inner query and I have some other queries on top of it , so after running entire query , it's taking longer time than usual , that is why I was trying to do something with indexes

Comment: If you are not sharing the entire query, you need to. Any change to a SQL makes it an entirely different SQL. You can't tune pieces of SQL without knowing the full SQL, because what parent query blocks are doing impacts how you want inner query blocks to work. Plus, you likely have issues elsewhere in the portions you aren't showing us.